# how to dynamically change worksheet object using c#

Tags: c#, excel-interop

This is my Sample Code

```
    Worksheet ws= (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];

     Excel.Worksheet ws2 = wb.Sheets.Add(missing, missing, 1, missing)
                    as Excel.Worksheet;


    ws.get_Range("A1", "K2").Merge(true);
    ws.get_Range("A1", "K2").Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
    ws.get_Range("A1", "K2").Font.Size = "14";
    ws.get_Range("A1", "K2").Font.Bold = true;
    ws.get_Range("A1", "K2").FillLeft();
    ws.Cells[2, 1] = "Line Chart Summary-BOTTOM";

above i using ws as object name .i want to change ws to ws1 using C# coding.


    ws1.get_Range("A1", "K2").Merge(true);
    ws1.get_Range("A1", "K2").Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
    ws1.get_Range("A1", "K2").Font.Size = "14";
    ws1.get_Range("A1", "K2").Font.Bold = true;
    ws1.get_Range("A1", "K2").FillLeft();
    ws1.Cells[2, 1] = "Line Chart Summary-BOTTOM"; Like this i want to change.
```

Using C# in .NET 3.5 with Visual Studio 2008, I am trying to set focus (or activate) a specific worksheet in an open workbook:for one user i use ws another user i use ws1 so i want to dynamically change the worksheet object.

Thanks Advance

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want to reference different worksheet with different user.

```
Worksheet wsTemp = null;

try
{    
    if (user == "A")
        wsTemp = ws1;
    else
        wsTemp = ws2;

    wsTemp .get_Range("A1", "K2").Merge(true);
    wsTemp .get_Range("A1", "K2").Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
    wsTemp .get_Range("A1", "K2").Font.Size = "14";
    wsTemp .get_Range("A1", "K2").Font.Bold = true;
    wsTemp .get_Range("A1", "K2").FillLeft();
    wsTemp .Cells[2, 1] = "Line Chart Summary-BOTTOM";

}
finally
{
    // release com object here
}
```